# Load table after function finish executing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which is hide by default and I want to display it only after a JavaScript (frameLooper()) function finishes executing.The JavaScript (frameLooper()) function render text messages during page load.I tried

```
 document.getElementById("myTypingText1").style.display = "";
```

but it won't work.
//css

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #myTypingText1 {
display: none;
}
</style>

<div id="myTypingText"></div> 
<table id ="myTypingText1" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
<caption><h3>Cash Flow and Releases Under Construction</h3></caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Overdue</th>
        <th>Batch No</th>
        <th>Collector</th>
        <th>Applicable year</th>
        <th>Borrower</th>
        <th>Area</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Under Construction</td>
        <td>Under Construction</td>
        <td>Under Construction</td>
        <td>Under Construction</td>
        <td>Under Construction</td>
        <td>Under Construction</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var myString = "blah blah balah blah blahautomatically notified by your programmer electronically...lets roll and keep our hands dirty..Drink beer eat kitkat..";
var myArray = myString.split("");
var loopTimer;
    function frameLooper() {
        if(myArray.length > 0) {
        var char = myArray.shift();
            if(char == "^"){
                document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += char;
                }
        } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
            return false;
        }
        loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',50);
        document.getElementById("myTypingText1").style.display = "";
    }
        frameLooper();           
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display = "";` isn't working because your CSS is overwriting it. put `display = "block";` (that's the default `visible` state and will overwrite the css)

you have another problem though which is that you're displaying the table after every time you render a character. You probably only want to display it when the animation is done? So you'll have to move that display code to where it'll only run when `myArray.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.I add a function in my javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var tble = document.getElementById("myTypingText1");
    tble.style.display = "none";
}
var myString = "Cashflow and releases is under construction.It's code is blah and balah and balh and blah automatically notified by your programmer electronically...lets roll and keep our hands dirty..Drink beer eat kitkat..";
var myArray = myString.split("");
var loopTimer;
    function frameLooper() {
        if(myArray.length > 0) {
        var char = myArray.shift();
            if(char == "^"){
                document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += char;
                }
        } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        showTable();
            return false;
        }
        loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',50);
    }
    function showTable(){
        document.getElementById("myTypingText1").style.display= "";
    }
    frameLooper(); 
    //showTable();
```